# In an inkscape extension, is there a way to close the options dialog?

Tags: inkscape

Is it possible to close the options dialog popup once the extension is run?

I feel it's kind of silly to have the options dialog hang in there once you've pressed "apply" (though not in all circumstances).

For clarity - this is an example of the dialog. Once you press apply, it just stays there and stares back at you.

[image]